# Why is the output `0` in this case?

Tags: c, post-increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *p = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        *(p + i) = i;

    printf("%d ", *p++);
    return 0;
}
```

So, I ran this code. Now I was told here that [Why won't the output be 4 in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669451/why-wont-the-output-be-4-in-this-case)  (in accepted answer) that `*p++` will increment pointer first and then dereference it. Therefore, in the above code, shouldn't the pointer be incremented first and then de-referenced and hence output should be `1`? Instead, output comes out to be `0`. Why?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: The answers given in the above post mostly say that we have to write unnecessary code, how is it relevant to my question?

Comment: you need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the precedence part right, but let's see about the postfix increment operator property, shall we?

`C11` standard says in chapter §6.5.2.4, *Postfix increment and decrement operators*

> **The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it). [...]

So, the variable itself will *experience* the effect of the increment, but the statement, in which the variable is present(with the postfix increment) will *avail* the existing value of the variable, not the incremented value. The increment, will be executed as a *side-effect* at a later part.

Answer (score 3):

This statement

```
printf("%d ", *ptr++);
```

does the following:

1. de-reference `ptr`, resulting in the value of `ptr[0]`
2. print out the `int` step 1 evaluates to, that is `ptr[0]`
3. increment `ptr` so it points to `ptr[1]`

To print out `ptr[1]` use:

```
printf("%d ", *++ptr);
```

Comment: Don't you think `*p++` will be treated as `*(p++)`? As `++` and `*` has same precedence and associativity will be from right to left .

Comment: @ameyCU: In short: No. Long reason here (from the C11Draft 6.5.2.4/2): "*The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
added to it). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
pointers. The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
updating the stored value of the operand.*" Keyword here: "*side effect*"

Comment: @ameyCU: You're right about the result, but actually postfix-operators (including increment) have *higher* precedence than unary-operators (like dereference).

Comment: @alk Yes .I got it . Thanks for that .

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it is post increment. Thus, the returned value of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand itself, then as a **side effect**, the value of the operand object is incremented.

The expression `*ptr++` will be

1. `*ptr`
2. use the value of `*ptr` as `printf("%d ", *ptr);`
3. `ptr = ptr + 1`

The output of such expressions can be understood by:

> 1. Precedence of **prefix ++** and `*` is same. Associativity of both is **right to left**.
> 2. Precedence of postfix ++ is higher than both `*` and **prefix ++**. Associativity of **postfix ++** is **left to right**.
>
> Therefore, in the above code, shouldn't the pointer be incremented first and then de-referenced and hence output should be 1?

Use for this requirement the following:

```
printf("%d ", *++ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should add `#include <stdlib.h>`. Secondly, you should correct your code `int *p = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));`.  Then the `*p++` stands for `1. printf *p; 2. p++`. If you want to get value 1, you should use the code `printf("%d ", *++p);`. I hope this can help you.